# Prove that $2^{(n^2)} = O(2^{2n} )$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I know that the O notation tells me to find $n_0$ natural and $c>0$ real, so the
  $$2^{(n^2)} \le c*2^{2n} $$
Only step that I can think about is this:
  $$2^{(n^2)} \le c*2^{n+n} $$
  $$2^{(n^2)} \le c*2^n*2^n $$
But I have no clue what to do next. (Some estimate?)

Do you have some hints please?

EDIT: sorry it should be $2^{(n^2)}$

Comment: $2^{n^2}$ is not $O(2^{2n} )$ since $\frac{2^{n^2}}{2^{2n}}\to\infty$.

Comment: Should the function be $(2^n)^2$ or $2^{(n^2)}$?

Comment: sorry $2^{(n^2)}$ is correct, already edited

Comment: Still utterly wrong, as my first comment shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is impossible. Assume that you have found such a $n_0$ and $c > 0$. Then
$$2^{(n-1)^2} =  2 \frac{2^{n^2}}{2^{2n}} \le 2c $$
for every $n \ge n_0$. This is clearly false since $\lim_{n \to \infty}2^{(n-1)^2} = \infty$.

Comment: sorry $2^{(n^2)}$ is correct, already edited

Answer (score 1):

This is, in fact, not true. Given a $c$, there is some natural number $m$ such that $2^m>c$. Now, for each $n>1+2\sqrt{ m+1}$ we have $n^2>2n+m$, which gives
$$
2^{n^2}>2^{2n+m}=2^{2n}\cdot 2^m>2^{2n}\cdot c
$$

Answer (score 0):

Your claim is false because $$\dfrac{2^{n^2}}{2^{2n}}=2^{n^2-2n}\to \infty$$ as $n\to\infty.$